# How can I get the position of an identified object in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, object-recognition

I can use Scikit-Learn to train a model and recognize objects but I also need to be able to tell where in my test data images the object is residing. Is there someway I could maybe get the coordinates of the part of the test image which has the object I'm trying to recognize?

If not, please refer me to some other library that'll help me achieve this task.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about a computer vision application. Usually, the way that a box is drawn around an identified object is by using a sliding window and running your classifier on each window as it steps across the screen. You can keep track of which windows come back with positive results and use those windows as your bounds. You may wish to use windows of various size, if the object scale changes from image to image. In that case, you would likely want to prefer the smaller of two overlapping windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, I've managed to recognize objects using SciKit-Learn. I've used the SIFT descriptor for feature detection and the Bag-Of-Words technique to achieve my goal. My program is very successfully able to recognize the object. All that's left now is creating a bounding rectangle around it. The technique you've mentioned doesn't really make sense here because SIFT is independent of scale and having a sliding window would just add to the computation, no? Could I, maybe, use OpenCV and some CV techniques to locate the object?